# Rename [osxelcapitan] to [osx-elcapitan]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

This tag was just created for the new release of [OSX/iOS](https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/), and it doesn't follow conventions.  This makes the tag hard to read.

[osxelcapitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osxelcapitan) should be [osx-elcapitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-elcapitan)

Comment: There's only two questions right now. Have you considered just editting them?

Comment: Can't the tag names conflict.  That is the first thing I did.  I suppose I could take them off, wait a day, hope that no new questions come up, and then put them back.  But a mod would be able to do this now.

Answer (score 2):

I've retagged the two questions with the offending tag.